# SQLite - onUpgrade() add column does not work

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

Hello I want to update my database to a version 2, but in the onUpgrade it does not work it does not add me new column.

So when I call on my method to record this puts me the following error message:

```
no such column: signature (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE invoices SET signature=? WHERE id = ?
```

Here is part of my code:

```
class InvoiceDatabase(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

companion object {
    private const val DATABASE_NAME: String = "invoice.db"
    private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 2
    private const val TABLE_NAME = "invoices" //Les nom de la base de donnee
    private const val COLUMN_ONE = "id" //COlonne UN, c'est le ID qui va sautoincrementer on va pas trop le toucher
    private const val COLUMN_TWO = "customercodez"
    private const val COLUMN_TREE = "idproducts"
    private const val COLUMN_FOR = "amountproducts"
    private const val COLUMN_FIVE = "discount"
    private const val COLUMN_SIX = "discounttype"
    private const val COLUMN_SEVEN = "date"
    private const val COLUMN_EIGHT = "signature"

    private const val DATABASE_ALTER_SIGNATURE  = "ALTER TABLE $TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN $COLUMN_EIGHT TEXT;"
}

/**
 * On creer la table SQLite
 */
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    val query: String = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${TABLE_NAME} (" +
            "${COLUMN_ONE} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "${COLUMN_TWO} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_TREE} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_FOR} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_FIVE} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_SIX} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_SEVEN} TEXT" +
            ");"

    db?.execSQL(query)
}
```

and my onUpgrade:

```
override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    when (oldVersion) {
        1 -> {
            db!!.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_SIGNATURE)
        }
        2 -> {
            //upgrade logic from version 2 to 3
        }
        3 -> {
            //upgrade logic from version 3 to 4
        }
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("onUpgrade() with unknown oldVersion $oldVersion");
    }

}
```

The methode i called:

```
fun addSignature(invoice: Invoice) {
    val values = ContentValues()

    values.put(COLUMN_EIGHT, invoice.signatureBitmap)

    val db: SQLiteDatabase = writableDatabase
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "${COLUMN_ONE} = ?", arrayOf(invoice.id.toString()))
    db.close()
}
```

all my code:

```
class InvoiceDatabase(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

companion object {
    private const val DATABASE_NAME: String = "invoice.db"
    private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 2
    private const val TABLE_NAME = "invoices" //Les nom de la base de donnee
    private const val COLUMN_ONE = "id" //COlonne UN, c'est le ID qui va sautoincrementer on va pas trop le toucher
    private const val COLUMN_TWO = "customercodez"
    private const val COLUMN_TREE = "idproducts"
    private const val COLUMN_FOR = "amountproducts"
    private const val COLUMN_FIVE = "discount"
    private const val COLUMN_SIX = "discounttype"
    private const val COLUMN_SEVEN = "date"
    private const val COLUMN_EIGHT = "signature"

    private const val DATABASE_ALTER_SIGNATURE  = "ALTER TABLE $TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN $COLUMN_EIGHT TEXT;"
}

/**
 * On creer la table SQLite
 */
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    val query: String = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${TABLE_NAME} (" +
            "${COLUMN_ONE} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "${COLUMN_TWO} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_TREE} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_FOR} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_FIVE} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_SIX} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_SEVEN} TEXT, " +
            "${COLUMN_EIGHT} TEXT" +
            ");"

    db?.execSQL(query)
}

/**
 * On insert lobjet creer dans la BDD
 */
fun insert(invoice: Invoice) {
    val values = ContentValues()

    values.put(COLUMN_TWO, invoice.customerCodeZ)
    values.put(COLUMN_TREE, invoice.idProducts)
    values.put(COLUMN_FOR, invoice.amountProducts)
    values.put(COLUMN_FIVE, invoice.discount)
    values.put(COLUMN_SIX, invoice.discountType)
    values.put(COLUMN_SEVEN, invoice.date)

    val db: SQLiteDatabase = writableDatabase
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)
    db.close()
}


/**
 * On Supprime l'objet de la bdd
 */
fun delete(invoice: Invoice) {
    val db: SQLiteDatabase = writableDatabase
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "${COLUMN_ONE} = ?", arrayOf(invoice.id.toString()))
    db.close()
}

/**
 * On modifie lobjet de la BDD
 */
fun update(invoice: Invoice) {
    val values = ContentValues()

    values.put(COLUMN_TREE, invoice.idProducts)
    values.put(COLUMN_FOR, invoice.amountProducts)
    values.put(COLUMN_FIVE, invoice.discount)
    values.put(COLUMN_SIX, invoice.discountType)

    val db: SQLiteDatabase = writableDatabase
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "${COLUMN_ONE} = ?", arrayOf(invoice.id.toString()))
    db.close()
}

fun addSignature(invoice: Invoice) {
    val values = ContentValues()

    values.put(COLUMN_EIGHT, invoice.signatureBitmap)

    val db: SQLiteDatabase = writableDatabase
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "${COLUMN_ONE} = ?", arrayOf(invoice.id.toString()))
    db.close()
}

/**
 * On recuperer toute les donnees de la bdd dans un arrayList
 */
val retrieveAllData: ArrayList<Invoice>
    get() {
        var count = 0

        val db = this.readableDatabase
        val invoices = ArrayList<Invoice>()

        val result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ${TABLE_NAME} ORDER BY ${COLUMN_ONE} DESC", null)

        while (result.moveToNext()) {
            invoices.add(count, Invoice(
                    result.getLong(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TWO)),
                    result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TREE)),
                    result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FOR)),
                    result.getDouble(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIVE)),
                    result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SIX)),
                    result.getLong(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SEVEN))
            ))

            invoices[count].id = result.getInt(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ONE))
            count++
        }

        return invoices
    }



override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    when (oldVersion) {
        1 -> {
            db?.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_SIGNATURE)
        }
        2 -> {
            //upgrade logic from version 2 to 3
        }
        3 -> {
            //upgrade logic from version 3 to 4
        }
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("onUpgrade() with unknown oldVersion $oldVersion");
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first when db object can be null, I would use somethink like :

db?.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_SIGNATURE) because with that, if db is null no code is executed so no crash. But with db!!.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_SIGNATURE) boom!!!

and now I see DATABASE_VERSION = 2 but you execute your alter table on version 1

Comment: sorry, I confirme ... Have you checked oldVersion return 1 ?

Comment: Yes because when I put DATABASE_VERSION = 1 and I launch my application I have an error message, you can not downgrade from version 2 to version 1. So the update of the version was made but the column does not not add

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen mon conseil sur le db?. au lieu du db!! reste pertinant je pense. Autre conseil aussi que je pourrais vous donner pour les migrations. Changez le code pour qu'un périphérique avec une version 1 qui passe directement à la version 3 de la base ai bien la migration de la version 2 de fait ainsi que celle de la 3. Parce-que là ce n'est pas le cas

Answer (score 0):

I provide java code for update some fields in table after upgrade database ..
change this code ..

```
override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
when (newVersion) {
    1 -> {
        db!!.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_SIGNATURE)
    }
    2 -> {
        getWriteDatabase();
    mNewDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TabelName ADD COLUMN COLUMN_EIGHT TEXT");
    }
    3 -> {
        //upgrade logic from version 3 to 4
    }
    else -> throw IllegalStateException("onUpgrade() with unknown oldVersion $oldVersion");
}
```

}

Here set one column value as zero for define all ids.

```
   mNewDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE TableName SET columnName = 0  WHERE TableName IN ('10','21','58','63','66','69','78','89','91','92','95','96','97')");
```

and if you want to add any column in the table then used alter command like below ..

```
mNewDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TabelName ADD COLUMN isActive INTEGER DEFAULT 1");
```

Comment: I do not understand the query update? why do it and where to put it?

Comment: i think you will perform update some field at the database upgrade time or add some column in table after updating database.

Comment: according your question table created issue or something else.

Comment: Nothing works, I updated my post can you look at my code?

Comment: which column you want to add which table.

Comment: COLUMN_EIGHT I WANT TO ADD

Comment: because you already define COLUMN_EIGHT at the table create time.

Comment: Yes my table already exists, with data in it, now I want to add the COLUMN_EIGHT without losing the data of the old column, so I also add the COLUMN EIGH to onCreate but it still does not work

Comment: Yes I also add in the onCreate but it does not work, it should be a solution to copy the whole database and transfer it in the new with the new column

Comment: No it is not right solution if you want to make only some change in to table after database upgration that time not create hall table again.

Comment: i update my answer update when condition take newDbversion. Try this.

Comment: no such column: signature (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE invoices SET signature=? WHERE id = ?